# dApp automated UI testing

Tags: testing, dapp, automation

I would like to set up integration automated UI tests for my dApp using Cypress, Puppeteer, or Selenium. At this point, the testing framework does not matter to me. Can anyone suggest ways to test the web3 and wallet interactions? I'm mainly concerned with message signing and transaction approvals.

I did find this small utility library for wallet mocking, but would prefer to test without mocking.
https://thlorenz.com/phan-wallet-mock/docs/index.html